# How to focus on a Material UI Button while Enter key pressing

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

[after the last inputing finished, user want to press save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQPnK.png)

'Tab' key will move the focus to the next element（button), I want use 'Enter' key realize this , but i did not how to do that ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: it is a simple problem , the description is enough , no need to say more .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ref` to focus the button when press Enter in the last input:

Firest, create ref:

```
const buttonRef = useRef(null);
```

Then, add ref in the button:

```
<button ref={buttonRef} ...>
```

After that, add `onKeyPress` in the last input to check press `Enter`:

```
<input onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} ...>
```

Anh this is the `handleKeyPress`:

```
  const handleKeyPress= e => {
    if(e.key === "Enter"){
      buttonRef.current.focus()
    }
  }
```